# Microsoft Message Queue

Tags: c#

I have windows application. Application reads message from MS
message queuing. Problem in application is some time don't read messages from message queues and threw this exception.

```
Thread was being aborted.
  at System.Messaging.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.MQReceiveMessage(MessageQueueHandle handle, UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
       at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
       at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
       at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive()
at Catalyst.CATS.DBService.OrdersQueueHandler.SynReceiveThreadMethod() in D:\svn\kinetic\Servers\Main DB Service\trunk\MainDatabaseServiceGUI\DBMainLogic\classes\OrdersQueueHandler.cs:line 143
```

I cant figure out the problem plz help me out

I have short code example below of my application.

```
public class Messages
{
private MessageQueue OrdersQueue;
OrdersQueue = MessageQueue.Create(".\\Private$\\DatabaseServerQueue", false);
OrdersQueue.SetPermissions("Everyone", System.Messaging.MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
OrdersQueue.SetPermissions("ANONYMOUS LOGON", System.Messaging.MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
OrdersQueue.UseJournalQueue = true;
public Messages()
   {
       thd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SynReceiveThreadMethod));
       thd.Start();
   }
private void SynReceiveThreadMethod()
{
    while(true)
        {
                try
                {
                 Message dequeuedMessage = OrdersQueue.Receive();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ee.StackTrace);
                }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: No point posting the exception without the code that caused it...

Comment: There is not enough detail to figure out the real exception. Please post the ENTIRE exception AND code you are using to read the message from the queue. you may also find it helpful using the trace logging. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx or

Comment: What is the exception message?  This looks like just a part of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

enable trace logging by adding this in the app config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="C:\logs\Log.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

you may need to tweak the setting a little to get it work but its mostly there
This will help diagnose the error correctly.